# Set capacity to array of model in Decodable protocol

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

I want to set a model array max capacity if the user has not logged in even JSON response contains more records.

```
public class AlertsInbox: Codable {
    public var messages: [Messages]?
    public init(messages: [Messages]) {
        self.messages = messages
        if !GlobalVar.isLoggedIn,
            let capacity = GlobalVar.messageCapacity {
            self.messages?.reserveCapacity(capacity)
        }
    }
}
```

Decode json response:

```
let responseMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode(AlertsInbox.self, from: data)
```

Using `reserveCapacity` in init of model but it gets overridden with the number of records received in response.

How to restrict while decoding?

Thanks

Comment: When you use any of the `Decoder`s the initializer that is called is [`init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init) not the one you wrote. Write your logic by implementing that initializer.

Comment: @nayem how to set limit in init(from decoder: Decoder) throws?

Comment: From what I understand, you need to limit the number of elements your array can hold. If that is the case, `reserveCapacity(_:)` isn't the way. You need to strip out the elements from your `limit` to `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not conditionally strip/drop out elements from an array in the `Type`'s initializer. This consideration is against the responsibility role of `Model` object. Instead it's a job for the controller object.

But you can have an access point in the model type. Let's say, you have a property `messages` in your `AlertsInbox` object. You can have another access point with another property, let's say, `limitedMessages` that will be a computed property.

Look at the below code. I intentionally changed the type's semantics from `Class` to `Struct`. But you are free to use as your need.

```
struct AlertsInbox: Codable {
    let messages: [Message]

    var limitedMessages: [Message] {
        // here you will use the value of your limit
        // if the limit exceeds the size of the array, whole array will be returned
        return Array(messages.prefix(5))
    }

    struct Message: Codable {
        let title: String
    }
}
```

Now you will use this, just like any other property, when you need the stripped out version of your actual messages. Like `alertInbox.limitedMessages` instead of the `messages` property.

---

But if you are not satisfied with the above and wanna stick to your plan, you can do that as well. See:

```
struct AlertsInbox: Codable {
    let messages: [Message]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let messages = try container.decode([Message].self, forKey: .messages)
        // the idea of limiting the element numbers is same as the above
        self.messages = Array(messages.prefix(5))
    }

    struct Message: Codable {
        let title: String
    }
}
```